# Spring: how to make thread-safe @Component?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-boot

I try to make my own token-based authorization for REST-service. Here is my TokenService:

```
@Component
public class TokenService {
    ...
    private Set<Token> tokens;
    private SecureRandom random;
    ...
    public TokenService() {
        this.tokens = new HashSet<Token>();
        this.random = new SecureRandom();
    }
    public boolean has(final String token) {
        clear();

        Token tokenStub = new Token(token);
        return this.tokens.contains(tokenStub);
    }
    public boolean remove(final String token) {
        Token tokenStub = new Token(token);
        return this.tokens.remove(tokenStub);
    }
    public Token retrieve(final TokenDetails tokenDetails) {
        clear();

        Token token = this.get(tokenDetails);
        if (token == null) {
            return gen(tokenDetails);
        }

        token.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        token.setTokenDetails(tokenDetails);

        return token;
    }
    ... //other methods
}
```

I am newbie in Spring Boot and I know about Spring Security, but I want to make my own security service. Is there any way to make my @Component class thread-safe with Spring Boot?

Comment: Why do you store tokens in memory? Don't you have a database? Anyway, you make a class thread-safe in Spring boot the same way you would do it in any other environment: by using thread-safe classes and/or synchronizing access to shared state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make your set threadsafe. You could use [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) instead of HashSet to make it threadsafe.

Comment: thank you for reply! But can i safely modify data in this collection?

Comment: you could use Hashtable that is synchronized

Comment: Big No no... HashTable performance would be bad compared to ConcurrentSkipListSet. Every method is synchronized of HashTable.